¿Por que mi metodo no forma un rectangulo?
Estoy tratando de escribir un método para una tarea. Mi método recibe tres parámetros (char c, int columnas, int filas) en base a ellos debería imprimir un rectángulo. Pero siempre me un resultado incompleto
public static void main(String[] args) {
   imprimeRectangulo('*', 3,4);
}

public static void imprimeRectangulo(char c, int columnas, int filas){

   for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){

      for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){

      }
      System.out.println(c);
   }
   System.out.println();
}//al final me devuelve solo esto en vez de un rectángulo.

Salida:
*
*
*
*

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme a entender que estoy haciendo mal, se lo agradecería mucho. Gracias

Es una buena idea que incluyas la salida esperada, si no, alguien podría escribir una respuesta que entregue un rectángulo distinto al que esperas.

Tienes 2 errores:

En tu segundo for no estas imprimiendo, este for debe ser el que imprima los asteriscos

En el System.out.println(c); que debería ir en el segundo for, estas realizando un salto de línea, esto te impedirá imprimir una fila entera, porque por cada carácter irás saltando a la línea siguiente. Debes usar System.out.print el cual imprime en pantalla sin saltar de línea


public static void imprimeRectangulo(char c, int columnas, int filas){

    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
           System.out.print(c);
        }
        System.out.println(); //este print es solo para saltar de línea a la siguiente
    }
    
}


Muchas gracias. Leí unas tres veces mas tu respuesta porque no estaba entendiendo que tenia que corregir (apenas estoy aprendiendo) pero ya quedo. ya pude entregar mi tarea gracias de verdad

@victorzaratearagon Disculpa no haber sido del todo claro, pero qué bueno que al final me lograste entender. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si es que te ha ayudado. Saludos
